# Do browsers cache error responses?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I am setting response headers for some requests as :

```
Cache-Control : "Private, max-age=21600";
```

If the same request fails, I retry for the same request. My doubt is whether browser caches such error responses, or not?

I tried simulating this scenario using fiddler. I returned `404-not found` for a request and checked `chrome://cache`, the cache contained this response with 404. When I removed the request from fiddler then I got 200 OK.

But still, I am not getting why browser had that 404 response in its cache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but yes Chrome caches 404 responses. You can add no-cache headers to prevent this; I think the HTML documentation even mentions it as well. There's some Apache/Nginx fix on this forum.

Comment: "HTML documentation" → Which documentation? “There's some Apache/Nginx fix on this forum.” → Link to it (and even copy the fix here).

Comment: I tried to use browser cache for 404 errors and I have found few weird scenarios. When I type in the URL "testsite.com/testblabla.png", we are getting an 404 response with e-tag and when I refresh the same browser tab it is not using the browser cache where as If I open the same url in a new tab it is getting from browser cache. It is so weird, also firefox is not using the browser cache for 404 status at all. Guys, please let me know if you also face the same issues

Comment: Based on recent tests Firefox is not caching 404s, but chrome is caching- what a mess :-(. 
The only solution for consistent behavior is to implement custom cache with CacheStorage and Service worker.